# Why isn't my index.html running?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm thinking it has to do with my heading, but couldn't find any errors. I ran it through the html validator and the only errors I got was not having alt attributes. Do you guys think this is a file path error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Timeline</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">



<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

<!-- Owl Carousel -->
<!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">

<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">

<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="owl/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<!-- end Owl Caorusel-->

</head>



<body>





<div id='page-wrapper'>




<!-- Begin Timeline--> 

<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">


  <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>1955 </h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet metus non rutrum  </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>1965 </h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet metus non rutrum </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


   <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>1975 </h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet metus non rutrum </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>1985 </h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet metus non rutrum </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>1996 </h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet metus non rutrum </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>1997</h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet metus non rutrum </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>1998 </h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet metus non rutrum </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>1999 </h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet  metus non rutrum </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>2000 </h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet metus non rutrum </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>2002 </h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet metus non rutrum </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>2010 </h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet metus non rutrum </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="item main-wrapper">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='main-wrap'>
                    <h1 class='main-year'>2015 </h1>
                    <h3 class='main-info'>ASDF INDUSTRIES IS FOUNDED </h3>
                    <p class='main-p'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et accumsan ante, quis fermentum sapien. Integer pellentesque aliquet metus non</p>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--end of main left side-->
            <div class='col-md-8'>
                <img src='http://i.imgur.com/fJJY6U2.png' class='img-responsive main-img'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



<!-- end of timeline -->
</div>


<!-- prev next buttons-->

<div class='hidden-lg hidden-md'>
    <div class='owl-buttons'>
        <div class='owl-prev'>
            <div class='icon-arrow-left'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='owl-next'>
            <div class='icon-arrow-right'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end prev next buttons-->  

<!-- dots-->
<div class='hidden-md hidden-lg'>
    <div class='owl-page'></div>
</div>
<!-- end dots-->


</div>

</div>
<!--end wrapper-->    

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: running in what way? and have you checked your code through the w3c validator because you're missing important HTML elements like `<head>` and `<body>`

Comment: where is the rest of your code ?

Comment: if that's the full html for your page and you have a blank page when you load it, congratulations, it's "running" exactly as it should

Comment: What do you mean by "not running"???

Comment: When I click on index.html on my folder nothing shows up. Sometimes it looks like it's loading for a very long time then nothing.

Comment: Try to load the script at the end

Comment: This line seems invalid to me: `src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">`. You're missing `http:`

Comment: @KyungmunBaek what you see here http://shehary.com/stackoverflow/runningaway.html

Comment: Which operation system? The right way is to run it within webserver and access the page in 'localhost' via your browser..

Comment: @I19, that'll only be a problem if he isn't running a local server. `//` with force the source to use whatever the local protocol is (whether it happens to be `http://` or `https://`). So unless he's running of the file system (using the `file://` protocol), the `//` is a non-issue.

Comment: @Mike The head and body tags are optional and not required in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several potential issues here, just a couple being that you need to check your file paths to ensure your css files are loading correctly, in addition, you need to add http: in front of your // jquery scripts they will not load properly as is if you are working locally.

Comment: lets suppose if he adds `http://` before jQuery and he is on SSL secure server, what will happen then?

Comment: @Shehary makes a good point. `//` should be a non-issue (unless he's running off the file system using the `file://` protocol).

Comment: @Shehary then his scripts will be pulled from their urls, or if he has them uploaded to his server from there, locally there is nothing to pull from.

Comment: @Josh Beam he said he is clicking his index file in his folder, sounds local.